# Batch file is working from cmd prompt but not from IIB tool

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have wrapped a simple perl command in a simple windows batch file and executed the same from cmd prompt which worked as expected.
But if I trigger the same batch file from my message flow in IBM Integration Bus, it is unable to recognize the 'perl' command.

Provided the environment variables are set properly and the batch file is working fine from command prompt.

Can anyone please help me on this to identify the issue and resolve the same?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please include the relevant details such as the batch, the failing batch command, environment variables...

Comment: please create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You say "Provided the environment variables are set properly", did you already try the `set` command in your batch command in order to see the environment variables??

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.

Actually the error was related to the path from where the batch is calling the perl command.

IIB was always executing it from it's runtime path and that's why it could not recognize the perl command.

The clue is to execute the batch from the path where the perl.exe is present. By following the same the issue got resolved.